# Refraction between two given points

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Five points in a vertical plane are given

$$ P1(0,0,-p),\, P2(0,0,0),\,I(x,y,0),\,Q1(a,b,q)\,,Q2(a,b,0)\,; $$

EDIT 1&2:

Simplify both ${x,y}$ to express them in terms of $(p,q,a,b,\mu)$ such that the following obtained result [Cross ratio of lengths for $\mu>1$ ] is the given starting point of Snell's Law.

$$\dfrac{\over{P2-I}} {\over{P1-I}} = \dfrac{\over{Q2-I}} {\over{Q1-I}}  \mu$$

Comment: Do you have any attempt at a solution?

Comment: I started to setup with Fermat principle this result.

Comment: Not sure I understant: Fermat principle states that the light goes through the quickest path. Knowing the speed in both medium you can then optimize for time and get directly Snell-Descartes' law. Is it what you are trying to do?

Comment: Yes, *after* such a procedure we obtain Snell's law as you stated. Now all I want is a more elegant algebraic simplified solution... as I got into a mess...

Answer (score 1):

Let's see about the mess.

I'll change the notation a little bit since I don't know exactly which is which in your question.

Let $A(x_1,y_1)$, $B(x_2,y_2)$ two points in two media, with an interface at $y=0$. Assume $y_1>0$ and $y_2<0$. You want to find a ray (or a guy, or anything), such that in the first medium its speed if $\nu_1$, while in the second medium its speed is $\nu_2$. You want to minimize the time to go from $A$ to $B$.

In a homogeneous medium, the shortest path is a line, so we are really looking for a path made of two lines, which both intersect the interface at some point $I(a,0)$. The unknown is $a$.

Let $d_1=AI$ and $d_2=IB$.

What's the time spent?

$$t(a)=\frac{d_1}{\nu_1}+\frac{d_2}{\nu_2}=\frac{1}{\nu_1} \sqrt{(a-x_1)^2+y_1^2}+\frac{1}{\nu_2} \sqrt{(x_2-a)^2+y_2^2}$$

We first see that $t$ is positive, $C^{\infty}$, and $t(a)\to+\infty$ as $a\to\pm\infty$, so there must be a minimum, and the first order condition means that at the minimum $t'(a)=0$. Also, geometrically, it's obvious that $a\in[x_1,x_2]$, otherwise there is a point in $[x_1,x_2]$ which would take less time (if $a_{min}<x_1$ take $a=x_1$, and if $a_{min}>x_2$ take $a=x_2$).

Here,

$$t'(a)=\frac{1}{\nu_1} \frac{a-x_1}{\sqrt{(a-x_1)^2+y_1^2}}+\frac{1}{\nu_2} \frac{a-x_2}{\sqrt{(x_2-a)^2+y_2^2}}=\frac{1}{\nu_1}\frac{a-x_1}{d_1}+\frac{1}{\nu_2}\frac{a-x_2}{d_2}$$

The equation to solve is thus

$$\frac{1}{\nu_1} \frac{a-x_1}{d_1}=\frac{1}{\nu_2} \frac{x_2-a}{d_2}$$

Let's have a look at what it means. In the right triangle $AIP$ with $P(a,y_1)$, the angle $\theta_1=AIP$ has sine:

$$\sin \theta_1=\frac{a-x_1}{d_1}$$

Likewise, in the right triangle $BIQ$ with $Q(a,y_2)$, the sine of $\theta_2=\widehat{BIQ}$ is:

$$\sin \theta_2=\frac{x_2-a}{d_2}$$

That is, at any local minimum of $t$, we must have

$$\frac{\sin\theta_1}{\nu_1}=\frac{\sin\theta_2}{\nu_2}$$

Which also proves that there is a unique local minimum (hence it's a global minimum), since $\sin\theta_1$ is an increasing function of $a\in[x_1,x_2]$, while $\sin\theta_2$ is a decreasing function of $a$.

Comment: Thanks for the effort taken to explain how Snell's Law. However I have given this as start point already  in my question and am looking to an algebraic simplification further on.

Comment: @Narasimham Maybe I didn't understand: you want to find something simpler than $\nu_2\sin\theta_1=\nu_1\sin\theta_2$? How much simpler?

Comment: When we are given two points one inside a dense medium and another outside.it ..what is required is $x_I= f(a,b,p,q,\mu),\, y_I= g(a,b,p,q,\mu)\, $

Comment: @Narasimham It's possible to write $x_I$ using a root of a polynomial of degree $4$. While the polynomial is not complicated, the roots are not nice. But it seems that answer was already given by Christian Blatter in [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22945/geometrical-construction-for-snells-law), where you also posted an answer.